# Rails 3 - Building a Table, Want to Alternate colors every row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Desired Output:

```
<ul>
 <li class="odd">stuff</li>
 <li class="even">stuff</li>
 <li class="odd">stuff</li>
 <li class="even">stuff</li>
 <li class="odd">stuff</li>
 <li class="even">stuff</li>
 <li class="odd">stuff</li>
 <li class="even">stuff</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.odd {color:blue}
.even{color:red;}
```

In rails 3 is there a clean way to do this without counters etc?

thanks

Comment: If you want to do it using Rails, listen to Raphomet.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Rails Way to do this is to use `cycle`.

```
<li class="<%= cycle('even', 'odd') -%>">stuff</li>
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle)

Comment: @BSeven `-%>` suppresses the newline, which you definitely wouldn't want in this case. I don't think `cycle` would ever append a newline so I assume that it is just the author's habit to always use it (for safety) though perhaps Raphomet can clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer [here](http://www.digimantra.com/technology/alternate-row-colors-ror/) that worked for me, here fleshed out a bit. Tested to work with Rails 3.2.8.

The `something.html.erb` file:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>foo</th>
    <th>bar</th>
  </tr>
  <% @something.each do |s| -%>
    <tr class="<%= cycle('oddrow', 'evenrow') -%>">
      <td> ... </td>
      <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The `something.css.scss` file:

```
table tr.oddrow {
    background-color: #111111;
}

table tr.evenrow {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking not really rails but a clean way achieving odd/even is with jquery on the client side:  http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Rails' TextHelper method: [cycle](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle).

```
<li class="<%= cycle('odd','even') -%>">stuff</li>
```

**Note:  'odd' should come before 'even' (not as listed above) or your designer might not be happy that the starting background-color didn't go as she planned.**